# Day trading in USA from Australia

Tags: united-states, taxes, stocks, australia, day-trading

I am an Indian citizen living in the USA for the past 4 years on work visa. I do trading occasionally (not day trading though), and as should be clear, I do have a SSN and Bank Account.

However, I would be relocating to Australia soon, and would like to know if I could still trade US stocks using US brokerage account from Australia? I would like to do day trading from overseas.If yes, is there any Tax implications that I need to take care off?

Please note that once I leave US, I would not be resident anymore, and my visa would get voided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could trade US stocks through an Australian broker, as many brokers here offer that facility. I am not sure if you are not a resident in the US anymore whether you can keep using a US broker, you would need to check with your broker for this, but my hunch is no, you won't be able to.

If you are trading in US stocks in Australia using an Australian broker you would pay any tax on profits earned in Australia.